# Drupal Webform Customization

Tags: javascript, theming

I'm using drupal 7, and I'm having a lot of trouble using the webforms.

I have a set of radio buttons, but each radio button needs to have an associated input field with it.

Code example:

```
<input type="radio" name="derp" /> option 1 : option 1 quantity desired: <input type="number" />
```

Note that this would span multiple rows, and is just to show the "layout" I am trying to achieve.

How can I add a "set" of input elements to a webforms radio select field?

Optional to answer but extra question: when I try to inject javascript into the webform using the markup option, my code is simply printed out onto the screen instead of being interpreted. Anybody know why?

Comment: Maybe you should try to use the form api in drupal.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to create your own webform component to ensure that validation and saving work as you intend. Look at an exisiting webform component to see how its done.